# How to "break" a continuous variable into discrete intervals using only ggplot2 commands

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a graph in ggplot with a `geom_sf` geometry. I can graph using `scale_fill_scontinuous`, however I would like to break my caption into discrete intervals, so that instead of using `scale_fill_scontinuous`, I can use `scale_fill_brewer`.
I wouldn't want to create an intermediate data.frame or a vector outside of ggplot.

Currently my chart looks like this:

```
ggplot(data=uniao3, aes(fill=`Área Úmida`))+
  geom_sf()+
  scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(0,20000),
                        breaks=c(500,2000,8000,15000,20000),
                        labels=c('500','200-2k','2k-8k','8k-15k','15k>'),
                        name="Wetland")+
    facet_wrap(~Ano)
```

out
[image]

I would like that instead of the legend (scale) to be presented as a gradient, it would be presented as blocks similar to this one:

[image]

I know the `scale_fill_brewer` command does this quite elegantly and efficiently, but how can I set my continuous variable to discrete inside ggplot?

Comment: You can use `cut` or `scale_fill_binned`

Comment: @Vinícius Félix  but `scale_fill_binner` doesn't let you set the caption colors with the `colours=c(....)` command.

Comment: I know you are requesting `ggplot` methods, but you could go down the `tmap` route and use `style = 'cat'` for this, if you're focus is on one single code block rather than `ggplot` specifically. https://geocompr.github.io/post/2019/tmap-color-scales/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go for `scale_fill_stepsn`, although there are multiple other solutions in the comments. That function takes care of discretizing a continuous variable according to your desired `breaks`, and it allows to use any colours in the `colours` vector (not just pre-brewed palettes).

Another advantage is that the *breaks and colour vectors do not need to match up in length*.

**Get an sf object**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1

# get sf data
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
```

**Use `scale_fill_stepsn`**

This is probably the easiest and most adequate way for *continuous* data which is cut into discrete slices.

```r
# set breaks and colours
breaks <- seq(0, 0.3, by = 0.02)
breaks
#>  [1] 0.00 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.10 0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.20 0.22 0.24 0.26 0.28
#> [16] 0.30

cols <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Spectral")
cols
#> [1] "#D53E4F" "#F46D43" "#FDAE61" "#FEE08B" "#FFFFBF" "#E6F598" "#ABDDA4"
#> [8] "#66C2A5" "#3288BD"

# plot
ggplot(data = nc, aes(fill = AREA)) +
  geom_sf() +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colours = cols,
                    breaks = breaks,
                    name = "area") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Note that I assigned the breaks and cols outside of the `ggplot` call for clarity, but you can of course specify them directly in the `ggplot` call.

**Use `scale_fill_brewer`**

This is more adequate for real *discrete* data, but also works for discretized continuous data.

Here, you need to do the cutting yourself, before setting the scale. Using `cut` with specified `breaks` in your `ggplot2` call will turn your numeric variable into a factor.

It is a bit less flexible regarding the choice of colours using `scale_fill_brewer`, because you need (?) to use an existing RColorBrewer colour palette.

This way, the colour legend looks more similar to your example legend, where each cut is labelled, rather than the break points.

```r
# plot
ggplot(data = nc, aes(fill = cut(AREA, breaks = seq(0, 0.3, by = 0.02)))) +
  geom_sf() +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual",
                    # labels = labels, # if you must
                    palette = "Spectral",
                    name = "area") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>